# Sharepoint 2007 calculated Date field shows incorrectly in non-US region

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-columns, date-format

If a SharePoint user (with Regional Settings set to UK) views a calculated date field in a View details form, the field shows incorrectly.

I am using:

ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@RenewalDate), 1033, 'dd MMMM yyyy')

Which shows 04 January 2010 for 01/04/2010 and, doesnt show unresolvable dates such as 31-Dec-2010.

This applies even with a simnple =[Modified] formula

The Server is set up in the US for that locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you change the formula as simnple =[Today] and check doest it works?

please try with the below formula

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Modified])),DAY([Modified])&" "&TEXT([Modified],"mmm")&" "&YEAR([Modified]),"")
```

And it is working fine for me. Pls try it and let me know what you are getting.

Comment: We can use Today in calculated field. It is a trick. 
Pls follow below site 
http://blogs.msdn.com/cjohnson/archive/2006/03/16/552314.aspx

Comment: I tried this and yes the problem occurs. I have added more detail above if you coulf take a look ! Thanks.

Comment: Excellent. £&$&£ing Sharepoint. I have created another field sourcing the original field as you specified and themn used that in the form. Many many thanks..